# Bootstrap col's aren't collapsing at breakpoint as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3.3.7

I have the following markup:

```
 <div class="homepage-casestudy container-fluid mt-25">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" style="border:1px solid green;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-4 homepage-casestudy__text" style="border:1px solid orange;">
                        <h4>Case Study</h4>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Read</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">See All</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="padding:0; border:1px solid red;">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1037x615" style="max-height: 300px" class="pull-right">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/0wu3vt2d/1/

The effect that I'm trying to create is to have a `.container-fluid` which contains a right aligned image (which seems to work ok). On the left of the image there is some text and buttons in a `.container`.

When it's on medium/large (`.md-`, `.lg-`) viewports it works ok, such as this:

[image]

But when it collapses to a mobile viewport, the image starts to "overlap" the text, e.g. 
[image]

I don't understand why this is happening because `.col-md-8` and `.col-md-4` add up to "12 columns" where Bootstrap normally collapses them on smaller viewports?

I want to hide the image - which seems to work using `.hidden-sm`, `.hidden-xs` - on smaller screens. This seems to work ok. But it still looks odd when resizing the browser window.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: try to add `col-xs` and `col-sm` as well for mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are after: https://jsfiddle.net/0wu3vt2d/2/

You were getting `pull/push` mixed up with `offset` and it was causing problems.

The attached fiddle changes the classes to be:

`col-sm-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 homepage-casestudy__text`

which means on small screens it has a grid offset of 4 and on big screens it has no offset, this can be tweaked accordingly of course for your liking but i believe this achieves what you wanted.

Comment: That's almost perfect. The only thing I need is for the text div (surrounded by the orange border) to be further over to the right - like a bit of padding/margin. That's why I was trying to use the `.container` and `-push` class.

Comment: Try changing the `col-md-offset-0` accordingly then, i would try `col-md-offset-2` @Andy

Comment: @Andy https://jsfiddle.net/0wu3vt2d/3/ see this fiddle, does that work?

Comment: The overall effect of that is perfect and exactly what I want. But if you resize your window and look very closely at the green/red border lines - they don't seem to look or do what you'd expect? It's like things aren't "collapsing" at the right point. I don't understand why. But that's besides fixing the problem I guess. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Andy it might be worth applying the borders and such to inner divs rather than the `col` divs, generally thats an easier way to manage problems like this, basically wrap the contents in another div and style them instead

Comment: Ok thanks. The borders were only for debugging purposes so I could see what's going on - they are not part of the eventual design. It just looks odd to me, but the end result is what I want, so thank you again.